# how to start Phonegap Android application from notification bar

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-3

I have a Android app with Google Cloud Message and Phonegap. Send, receive are done.
I try to launch my app from notification bar. But have problem:

```
This isn't the root activity. Clearing it and returning to the root activity.
```

How to fix it?

---

PendingIntent when create notification:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PushHandlerActivity.class);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
notificationIntent.putExtra("pushBundle", extras);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Force main activity load

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

When i click to notification, it run Intent PushHandlerActivity, and PushHandlerActivity force main activity load. When the main activity load it say "This isn't the root activity. Clearing it and returning to the root activity." in LogCat, and my app can't show up :(

Answer (score 0):

Please look for my code. It works absolutely fine for me

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;


        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: Problem in load application from notification bar, not in show a notification. When i click to notification, it run intent PushHandlerActivity, and launch package but not show application.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change:

```
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

With

```
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(<PackageNameOfYourMainActivity>);
```

Than it will start your PhoneGap main activity.

I didn't try this, it's just looks logical to me.